# xsd -xml regex validation not working for me using JAXB

Tags: xml, spring, xsd, jaxb

I have written a simple XSD where I have written following XSD pattern

```
<xsd:element name="xx">
<xsd:simpleType  >
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern
            value="^[a-z]+">
        </xsd:pattern>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

When I execute XML-XSD validation using jaxb always error is encountered of XX tag. ex:

```
<xx>abcd</xx>
```

I am not sure why this strange behavior ? I hope my regex is correct and above example should pass validation.Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 7):

You need to remove the anchor ^ from the expression.  XSD validators do not recognise the ^ or $ anchors, but interpret them as literal characters.  You can verify this by changing your XML to `<xx>^abcd</xx>` and validating it against your current XSD.

The reason for this is that your pattern is automatically bound to the beginning and end of the string.  Unlike regexes where you try to match a value, this regex is to validate the entire contents of the element, so you have to create a pattern to fully match everything that appears in the field.